# Backbone - Render view after multiple events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone `View` which I want to render only after two different events have happened. The two events are two different `Collections` being populated from the server (this is to populate two dropdown select lists).

My two `Collections` are `cFilterFields` and `cFilterOperators` and both have a custom `.populate()` method which calls `.fetch()` and fires `populated` events.

This is what I have:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this,'render');

        this.fields = new cFilterFields();
        this.operators = new cFilterOperators();

        this.fields.populate();
        this.operators.populate();

        this.listenTo(this.fields,'populated',function(){
            // ...
        });
        this.listenTo(this.operators,'populated',function(){
            // ...
        });

    },
    events: {},
    render: function(){
        // ...
        return this;
    }
});
```

What is the best way to render this `View` when **both** `Collection` events have fired...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the collections' `populate` methods return promises and then use [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Your initialize should then look something like this

```
$.when(fields.populate(), operators.populate())
  .done(_.bind(function() {
      this.render();
  }, this));
```

This solution assumes JQuery and underscore because both are dependencies of Backbone.

Comment: Are you certain that jQuery is a dependency of Backbone.js? I ran Backbone.js with just Underscore.js a while back with no problems.

Comment: @ivarni Thanks, that's an interesting way of doing it. I've actually just done it a different way - answer posted.

Comment: @ojrask Yes, http://backbonejs.org/ says *For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include jQuery* and since OP is calling render I felt it was safe to assume jQuery to be available.

Comment: @ivarni Was just checking and found the same paragraph. _.js was the only *hard* dependency for running Backbone. Good to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just done it, simple really, you just do:

```
this.listenTo(this.fields && this.operators,'populated',function(){
    this.render();
});
```

**UPDATE**

Don't use this, see comments below, I'll be accepting the correct answer.

Comment: Can't see this anywhere in Google search results or the documentation. Need to try it out ASAP.

Comment: I know, it seems to be working for me though, I'll do more tests now I think to make sure...

Comment: @ojrask It seems to be reliable. I've added `console.log`'s to both collections and to the `listenTo()` multiple objects code above, and it is showing in the console correctly. Both my dropdown select lists are populated with data before the `View` is rendered. But you're right, I can't find this anywhere else after doing multiple Google searches. I'd be interested to hear your results after trying this out...

Comment: I am looking at the [source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L117) trying to figure out why it works, no luck so far :)

Comment: Note: Running `({a:1} && {b:2})` in console returns only the second object. It's possible that you're really only listening to `this.operators`.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure this doesn't actually work, see http://plnkr.co/edit/HQRmXzJn75Wla9HQr5SA?p=preview

Comment: @ivarni Thanks for that, I see what you mean... I'll try the way you suggested now. :-)

Comment: I think that's the cleanest option unless you want to start messing around with boolean flags to keep track of events.